# Checar se cookies existe em ASPNET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp-net-core

Estou migrando do **asp.net WebForms** para o **Core 2.2** e no aplicativo, armazenávamos informações como Id, e outros parâmetros. No Asp.Net Core uso o Seguinte IActionResult para gravar o cookie:

```
public IActionResult GravaCookie(string setting, string settingValue, bool isPersistent)
    {
        if (isPersistent)
        {
            CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions();
            options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            Response.Cookies.Append(setting, settingValue, options);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append(setting, settingValue);
        }
        ViewBag.Message = "Cookie Armazenado!!!";
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Para recuperá-lo eu uso o seguinte código:

```
ViewBag.FontName = Request.Cookies["fontName"];
```

Pelo WebForms eu verificava com o seguinte código:

```
if (Request.Cookies["EstaAtivo"].Value != null)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/garantido");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/entrar");
}
```

Como eu faço a mesma verificação pelo Asp.Net Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só fazer assim:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Cookies["EstaAtivo"]))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/garantido");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/entrar");
}
```

porque o `Request.Cookies["EstaAtivo"]` retorna uma tipo [string](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8).

Pode fazer assim também:

```
string EstaAtivo = Request.Cookies["EstaAtivo"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EstaAtivo))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/garantido");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/entrar");
}
```

Comment: Interessante, a segunda forma funciona, já a primeira não teve efeito. 
Pelo visto precisa declarar o cookie como string para ver se ele existe mesmo!

Comment: As duas formas funcionam @ClaudineiFerreira ...